# Extend Django's ManyToManyField with custom fields

Tags: python, sql, django, model, manytomanyfield

I am working on a project that uses multiple ManyToManyFields, however, at this point I realize that I want the ManyToManyField to store some extra values (mostly automatically set), such as a timestamp for when the connection was created. I tried this, and replaced the reference to `models.ManyToManyField` with my custom `ManyToManyField`

```
class CustomManyToManyField(models.ManyToManyField):
    date_registered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And then my models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class B(models.Model):
    m2m = CustomManyToManyField(A)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

However, running `python manage.py sql testapp` returns the following SQL:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "testapp_a" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(32) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "testapp_b_m2m" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "b_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "a_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "testapp_a" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("b_id", "a_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "testapp_b" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(32) NOT NULL
)
;
```

It doesn't take into account the `date_registered` field I defined in the extended `CustomManyToManyField`. Why not?

Answer (score 7):

This is not the correct way to do it. See [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) in the Django documentation.

Besides, the `CustomManyToManyField` you created is a custom **field**, not a model, so it can't contain fields.

Comment: Thank you. I found this page immediately after posting my question. Huge brain fart on my part.